# How does Warding Bond interact with curse effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, curses

My DM and I were wondering about curses while *warding bond* is active.

A paladin has *warding bond* with the cleric and is attacked by a wereboar. The paladin passes his lycanthropy curse check. Would the cleric also have to make the same check to be cursed with lycanthropy?

Comment: Hi SoundFX, it seems that you've made a duplicate account. This means that your edit is being treated as though a second user is trying to edit "your" question. You can merge the accounts using [this guide](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), but unfortunately, until you do so, the system will not recognise you as the owner of this question, since it belongs to your "old" account, and your "new" account will not be able to comment on these posts nor accept your favourite answer (& your edits will have to go through review queues as though you're editing someone else's posts).

Comment: Cool, looks like you were able to log into your original account again. Sorry for the inconvenient intro to the site, hope you stick around!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The cleric would not need to make a saving throw

The *[warding bond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/warding-bond)* spell says:

> While the target is within 60 feet of you, it gains a +1 bonus to AC and saving throws, and it has resistance to all damage. Also, **each time it takes damage, you take the same amount of damage.**

The cleric will suffer only the damage (halved) that the paladin receives from the wereboar. The curse is not damage, so *warding bond* does not transfer that to the cleric.

From the wereboar's Tusks action:

> If **the target** is a humanoid, **it** must succeed on a DC 12 Constitution saving throw or be cursed with wereboar lycanthropy.

Here "it" refers to "the target", which was the paladin in this case. The cleric is not the target, and the damage (and only the damage) is only transferred because of *warding bond* (i.e. the cleric is not a target of the attack, they are effectively being damaged by their own spell).

So the cleric would not need to make a saving throw, as they are not the target of the lycanthropy curse.